# Heroku : App crashing with deployment of 'surespot' web-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, coffeescript

I am trying to deploy opensource project 'SureSpot' as a heroku app to experiment with it for research purposes. The github link is : https://github.com/surespot/web-server and its written in CoffeeScript running on NodeJs server. The databases used are Cassandra and Redis.

I am a beginner to NodeJs, CoffeeScript and Heroku as well but tried to get a good grasp before initiating. I would request someone with good experience of CoffeeScript to look the main code and then the log (shown below) to tell what can be the issue. This project looks different because it doesn't have the app.coffee file while error is "app.js not found" also it doesn't have Procfile.

Log :-

---

2014-02-23T13:57:57+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-02-23T13:58:10.217762+00:00 app[web.1]: > surespot@0.0.1 start /app
2014-02-23T13:58:10.248303+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2014-02-23T13:58:10.217765+00:00 app[web.1]: > app.js
2014-02-23T13:58:10.235175+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: app.js: not found
2014-02-23T13:58:10.244028+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! surespot@0.0.1 start: `app.js`
2014-02-23T13:58:10.244094+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 127
2014-02-23T13:58:10.248197+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2014-02-23T13:58:10.244903+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the surespot package,
2014-02-23T13:58:10.244236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-02-23T13:58:10.244330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the surespot@0.0.1 start script.
2014-02-23T13:58:10.245091+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-02-23T13:58:10.245276+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

2014-02-23T13:58:11.583912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-02-23T13:58:11.592310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-23T13:58:52.453695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=testapp1.herokuapp.com request_id=88ea034e-7630-4303-8973-8bda32a94ec6 fwd="138.246.2.71" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

---

The package.json file : https://github.com/surespot/web-server/blob/master/package.json states

```
"scripts": {
"start": "app.js"
```

},

so maybe thats why it is looking for app.js.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

Wahib

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the package.json has incorrect info. You need to run it by invoking "server/cluster.coffee". You can create a Procfile to do that. However, you also need to set a variety of environment variables. I would recommend trying to get it running correctly on your local machine first before deploying to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks dankohn for the reply. Have you already tried running this project ? Yes, it makes more sense now to deploy correctly on local machine first. I was just in a hurry and didn't expect that an opensource project like this will be a hassle.

Comment: Heroku supported the `start` variable from package.json specifically so that more open source projects would run correctly on Heroku without needing a Procfile. However, that requires the projects do the work. If you get it working and like the project, please create a pull request with the changes needed.

Comment: anyone else who reach this thread looking for the same issue then do checkout this communication i had with one of the code authors https://github.com/surespot/web-server/issues/2